# Asp.net classic application pool mode getting slow in Windows 2016 server

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-10

Can you please help to diagnosis the problem in ASP.Net classic mode application pool getting slow in IIS 10, it is not happening every day. Sometime it is working getting for 2 to 3 days, then suddenly it is getting slow. Sometime it is getting slow for 2 to 3 hours then working fine.

Same application is hosted on other server and also hosted at cloud, but only one site having this issue.

Tried below:

> windows defender online protection turn off
>   Antivirus exclude the publish directory
>   Change Web.config

blank asp.net page also getting slow

getting below error, may be it could be the reason

The state server has closed an expired TCP/IP connection. The IP address of the client is 127.0.0.1. The expired Read operation began at 09/27/2019 08:25:10.

Comment: Welcome to SO @SarojPradhan. Why do you want to run an ASP.NET application in a classic ASP application pool?

Comment: ho is this related to `sql-server` tag?

Comment: I suggest you could try to use debugdiag tool to capture the performance dump for the application pool and use debugdiag analysis to analysis the dump to find out which function is very slow.More details about how to use it, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h).

Comment: @MikePoole: Application using AjaxPro.2.dll and migrated from VS 2005 to VS 217, so it is required to run Apps pool as classic mode

Comment: @B3S: Apps is using SQL, so it may possible that SQL getting deadlock and apps getting hanged, so it is tag with SQL also.

Comment: @BrandoZhang thanks for you suggestion and link, we will be tried and share the result